# How to covert a h2o coefficients table into a model object in R

Tags: r, model, h2o, glm, predict

UPDATE...
so I kinda figure out my problem in other way and I will leave my code below.....

Another thing is, I'd still like to know if a dataframe(with coefficients in table) can be converted to a model object like glm ...??

=================================================

so I am learning h2o package in R and I have a problem in getting model from h2o object:

So, I have went through the h2o training session and got my S4 object "fit",
by subset this "fit" object I can get model and coefficients table;
the question is , how do I use this "coefficients table" as a model, like what we usually do in glm ?

Here is the code:

```
#using dataset germancredit as sample

data("GermanCredit")
#ease for demo
Sub_German=GermanCredit[  ,c("amount","present_residence","duration","age")]    
target=ifelse(GermanCredit$credit_risk=="good",0,1)

data=cbind(Sub_German,target)


library(h2o)

localH2O = h2o.init()

dth2o = as.h2o(data)  


# h2o.glm  
fit = h2o.glm(y="target", training_frame=dth2o,  seed=17,
              family="binomial", nfolds=2, alpha=1, lambda_search=TRUE) # summary(fit)


model_fit_h2o= fit@model
class(model_fit_h2o)
# [1] "list"

model_fit_coe_table= model_fit_h2o$coefficients_table
class(model_fit_coe_table)
# [1] "H2OTable"   "data.frame"


# predict
dt_h2o_pred= predict(fit, type='response', dth2o)
class(dt_h2o_pred)
# [1] "H2OFrame"

# convert to dataframe and get p1 as predicted probability for '1'
dt_h2o_pred_df=as.data.frame(dt_h2o_pred) 
dt_h2o_num=dt_h2o_pred_df$p1
class(dt_h2o_num)
# [1] "numeric"
```

So as seen, how do I convert this "model_fit_coe_table" into a model object?
What I usually do is using glm, as shows :

```
# glm ------
model = glm(target ~ ., family = binomial(link='logit'),  data = data)
summary(model)

# Select a formula-based model by AIC
m_step = step(model, direction="both", trace=FALSE)
model_fin = eval(m_step$call)
class(model_fin)
# ("glm" "lm")


#predicted proability
dt_pred = predict(model_fin, type='response', data)
```

In this case I can apply "predict" function with "model_fin" of type glm.

Admittedly, I think I could manually create a logistic function like 
f(x)= ax1+bx2+cx3....+cont,  using the coef table from h2o object;

but if I'm playing with the independent variables , this means I need do this by hand every time I change input...so this is totally inefficient....

Anyone got any solutions? Or is there another way to achieve my goal?
Thank you!!

Comment: Please update your example to use a public dataset (e.g. iris) so that it's reproducible. Thanks.

Comment: What is the objective of your exercise here?